# Trying to center two items and make them responsive?

Tags: wordpress, class, responsive-design, center

Maybe someone can help me out. I am working on a mock web page in WordPress and I am running into a small issue. Two of the divs are centered on my 17in PC screen but when I look at them on a desktop, they are the only two divs that are not centered on the screen and are not responding when I shrink a window down. The two divs / classes that I am working with are .headerwrap and .ibanner.

Here is the code for just the .headerwrap:
    .headerwrap {
    display: block; 
    min-height: 88px;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    width: 1200px; 
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 185px; 
    vertical-align: middle; }

and the .ibanner is: 
    .ibanner { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #95C837;
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin-top: 20px; width: 1200px;
    margin-left: 185px; 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
   vertical-align: middle; }

The website is: http://bitlamp.wctc.edu/~ktepp/StellarBlueTechnologiesTest/

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please directly post the code that is relevant to the question your asking.

Comment: I can but since it is done in WordPress with a theme the CSS is pretty lengthy.

Here is the code for just the .headerwrap:
.headerwrap {
 display: block;
 min-height: 88px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 width: 1200px;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 185px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}


and the .ibanner is:
.ibanner {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #95C837;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 1200px;
 margin-left: 185px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
 vertical-align: middle;
}